# Setting up prefered versions in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to set up an .htaccess file. I wanted to set it to go to just the route of the current folder if the user include index.php and index.html at the end of the address.
I was want the www to be added to the address if the user missed it out.

I'm running two websites from the same address. One is using the root folder and the other from a folder. The index bit works fine for both but when I set the www, if they miss it out, it goes to the home page on the root rather than the folder.
Could anyone suggest what I need to do here and where I should put the .htaccess file to get it to work?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^candle-light\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.candle-light.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.candle-light.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The subfolder is called flickering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules with `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable instead of `$1`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^candle-light\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(?:html|php)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Do I need to add in an extra couple of lines or can I modify what's already there to remove index.html as well?

Comment: What I meant was, the last two lines of your code remove index.php. Can I modify those lines to remove index.html as well or do I need to add two more lines to deal with index.html?

Comment: That's done it. Thank you so much. You are a real star.

Comment: I've got a link on the page. The url is '#' becuase it has on onclick function on it which submits a hidden form. This doesn't work and it worked before I set this up.     

<form method="post" action="index.php" name="admin">
      <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="1"/>
      <h1>
        <a href="#" style="color: #ff0000; text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:document.admin.submit()">Candle Light</a>
      </h1>
    </form>

Is there any way I can still allow that to work?

Comment: POST data gets lost after redirection. Better to skip POST request for redirects. Check updated answer now.

Comment: That works now. I assume when someone goes to the website it will redirect them to the correct version (add the www and remove the index.php). After then, when they click on the link to post the form that they are already in the correct place so it doesn't need to redirect them again. Is that correct?

Comment: There is no impact to GET variable with these rules. Your problem might be due to some other issue.